# Can't execute system call "execve"

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, execve

I am a newbie so I could be inacurate with expressions. I need to make a system call "execve" in C with assembler. I don't use any libraries. Part that doesn't work is

```
char *nul=(char *)0;
char *argv[] = { "/bin/date", nul };
char *envp[] = { nul };
long ret;
asm volatile ("int $0x80" : "=a" (ret) : "a" (11), "b" (argv[0]), "c" (argv), "d" (envp));
//"a" (11) ... 11 correspondes to execve
```

I compile the code (and get neither errors nor warnings) with

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -static -O2 sysc.c -o sysc
```

When I try to run the program I see this message:

```
A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.
Aborted
```

Comment: Did you try passing `&argv` via ecx?

Comment: Why do you need to use assembler to call a C function from a C program? (I'm not saying there's no possible reason, but knowing your goal might help in answering the question.)

Comment: `c` should also be `argv[0]`. Pointers to arrays are incredibly rare and useless in C; typically you always operate on the pointer to the first *element*.

Comment: @ccKep I did, doesn't help.

Comment: @KerrekSB nope, doesn't work either

Comment: @RomanSushkov: It wasn't meant to help, just to fix the types in your call :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can the execve system call run "/bin/sh" without any argv arguments, but not "/bin/ls"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673765/why-can-the-execve-system-call-run-bin-sh-without-any-argv-arguments-but-not)

Comment: Before closing as a duplicate, can anyone confirm (1) ASM does not affect the issue; and (2) `/bin/date` falls under coreutil's umbrella and exhibits the same behavior as `/bin/ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the generated code, you'll see that the compiler optimized away the initialization of `argv` and `envp`, on the assumption that your asm block is not accessing them (since you only declare that you need the pointers themselves).

Solution: add a `"memory"` clobber to tell the compiler that you may read or write any memory.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the `exec()` family of functions are a bit strange.

In particular, arg0 and arg1 are roughly same thing:

```
char *args [] = {"./path/to/program", "arg1", "arg2", NULL};

int rc = execve (args[0], args, envp);
```